# Why am I getting a Seg Fault when creating threads?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stdthread

I am confused as to why I am getting a segmentation fault when creating and firing off threads here. It happens in the `t[j] = thread(getMax, A);` line and I am very confused as to why this is happening. `threadMax[]` is the max of each thread. `getMax()` returns the maximum value of an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <thread>
#define size 10
#define numThreads 10
using namespace std;

int threadMax[numThreads] = {0};
int num =0;

void getMax(double *A){
    num += 1;
    double max = A[0];
    double min = A[0];
    for (int i =0; i<size; i++){
        if(A[i] > max){
            max = A[i];
        }
    }
    threadMax[num] = max;
}

int main(){
    int max =0;
    double S,E;
    double *A = new double[size];
    srand(time(NULL));
    thread t[numThreads];
    //Assign random values to array
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        A[i] = (double(rand()%100));
    }
    //create Threads
    for(int j =0; j <numThreads; j++){
        cout << A[j] << "    " << j << "\n";
        t[j] = thread(getMax, A);
    }

    //join threads
    for(int i =0; i< numThreads; i++){
        t[i].join();
    }

    //Find Max from all threads
    for(int i =0; i < numThreads; i++){
        if(threadMax[i] > max){
            max = threadMax[i];
        }
    }

    cout <<max;

    delete [] A;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `numThreads`? `getMax`? Please provide [mcve].

Comment: numThreads is just a define variable which defines there to be 10 threads that are going to be created.

Comment: Don't explain the code. Provide [mcve] instead.

Comment: #define numThreads 10

Comment: getMax() returns max value of an array

Comment: @Matt: If "we" (viewers) can't compile your code (minimal reproducible example), it's hard to tell what your bug is. For example, if `size` isn't the same as `numThreads`, well, that could be one particular bug.

Comment: Please use the Edit link to edit your question and make your program complete.

Comment: @Matt Why is it so hard, to [edit] your question with the [mcve]? Did you try to read the link, that I provided, so you can learn what it is?

Comment: after filling in the blanks your code works:https://wandbox.org/permlink/pC3hbMv8ZKATzi2E, please provide a [mre]

Comment: There is also no `threadMax` defined anywhere in this, but is used in the final loop. Please, imagine what we know about your code is **only** what you posted. We don't have your source file. We don't have your `#include` stack, your global variables, hard macros, etc. Therefore *we can't reproduce your issue*. Therefore, at best you're going to get WAGs (wild-arse-guesses), which are unproductive and make for terrible long-term answers. [Update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58310249/edit) so as to provide a [mcve] and we can probably help.

Comment: Here is some updated code

Comment: `num += 1;` is not synchronized. Multiple threads may try to read from/write to `num` at the same time.

Comment: @helloWorld123 The bottom line is that multithread programming isn't about just knowing how to start threads.  You have to learn synchronization techniques -- mutexes, atomic variables, race conditions, etc.  It is not a trivial topic.

Answer (score 5):

The behavior of this code is undefined:

```
 void getMax(double *A){
        num += 1;
        double max = A[0];
        double min = A[0];
        for (int i =0; i<size; i++){
              if(A[i] > max){
                        max = A[i];
                }
        }
        threadMax[num] = max;
}
```

The `num += 1` can allow multiple threads to attempt to modify `num` at the same time. Worse, when `num` is read in the `threadMax[num] = max;`, threads may see values of `num` modified by other threads while they were running.

You need to assign each thread a number in some safe way.

Here are three ways it can fail:

1. Two threads do `num += 1;` at exactly the same time and as a result, `num` only increments once.
2. Every thread does `num += 1;` before any thread does `threadMax[num] = max;`. All threads overwrite the same entry in the array. (Which, actually, is out of bounds!)
3. The code crashes because its behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, your `num` variable is not protected from race conditions inside of `getMax()`, which can lead to it being corrupted, thus causing `getMax()` to access the `threadMax[]` array out of bounds.

You can avoid that by simply getting rid of that `num` variable altogether and pass the array index as an input parameter to `std::thread` instead.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

const size_t size = 10;
const size_t numThreads = 10;

double threadMax[numThreads] = {};

void getMax(int idx, double *A){
    threadMax[idx] = *max_element(A, A + size);
}

int main(){
    srand(time(nullptr));

    vector<double> A(size);
    array<thread, numThreads> t;

    //Assign random values to array
    generate_n(A.begin(), size, [](){ return double(rand() % 100); });
    /* or:
    for(double &d : A){
        d = double(rand() % 100);
    }
    */

    //create Threads
    for(int j = 0; j < numThreads; ++j){
        cout << A[j] << "    " << j << "\n";
        t[j] = thread(getMax, j, A.data());
    }

    //join threads
    for(thread &thd : t){
        thd.join();
    }

    //Find Max from all threads
    double max = *max_element(threadMax.begin(), threadMax.end());
    cout << max;

    return 0;
}
```